# groupBy as indexed array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose I have a collection like this:

```php
$collection = [
  App\User {name: 'Bob', age: 20},
  App\User {name: 'Joe', age: 22},
  App\User {name: 'Lisa', age: 20}
]
```

and I group them like `$collection->groupBy('age')`. I get this result:

```php
[
  "20" => [
    App\User {name: 'Bob', age: 20},
    App\User {name: 'Lisa', age: 20},
  ],
  "21" => [
    App\User {name: 'Joe', age: 22}
  ]
]
```

I'd like to remove the associative keys and just use an indexed array, like this:

```php
[
  [
    App\User {name: 'Bob', age: 20},
    App\User {name: 'Lisa', age: 20},
  ],
  [
    App\User {name: 'Joe', age: 22]
  ]
]
```

Is this possible to do with a Laravel collection method? Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_values`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

```php
array_values($collection->groupBy('age'));
```

More Laravel way would be

```
$collection->groupBy('age')->values();
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can use `->unique()` instead groupBy. In this helper, it is indexed from zero.